# Java regex pattern mathes not valid optional part

Tags: java, regex

I have following regex pattern in code:

```
"(?<part1>(?<year>\\d{4})(?<day>\\d{3})(?<number>[A-Z0-9]{3})(?<sequence>\\d{4}))-(?<lastPart>(?<letter>[A-Z0-9]+)_?(?<num1>\\d+)?_?(?<num2>\\d+)?)"
```

and i have changed it to following, to made `<lastPart>` optional:

```
"(?<part1>(?<year>\d{4})(?<day>\d{3})(?<number>[A-Z0-9]{3})(?<sequence>\d{4}))-?(?<lastPart>(?<letter>[A-Z0-9]+)_?(?<num1>\d+)?_?(?<num2>\d+)?)?"
```

i'm updating it because 14 digits string is valid too, but running tests i have found that invalid strings

```
20221239990001_AB
20221239990001_ABC#$%
20221239990001_+AB><
20221239990001_-*AB___
20221239990001_AB12232434
```

are valid too and it is wrong.
How to make my regex pattern validate 14 digits string as a first part and if something presented after, it should looks like `-{numbers/letters}_{numbers}_{numbers}`
Thanks.
Edit1:

not matching:

```
2022123999000
202212399900
2022123999
```

but what is weird `12321324143432142352546534636534343243525425` is matching.

Edit2:
Optional part contains optional subparts
so:

```
12233255555555 valid
12233255555555- invalid
12233255555555-A valid
12233255555555-A_ invalid
12233255555555-A_1 valid
12233255555555-A_1_ invalid
12233255555555-A_1_1 valid
12233255555555-A__1 invalid
12233255555555-A__ invalid
```

Comment: You should include sample data both matching and non matching.

Comment: can you try this and let me know whether this worked for all test cases you mentioned  `^\d{14}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+_\d+_\d+)?$`

Comment: For starters your pattern has `-` where your examples have `_`, and your "number" group allows letters (?) but your examples don't have letters there. Also, please remove all the group names - it's hard enough to read regex without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... i have changed it to following, to made `<lastPart>` optional ...
>
>
>
> ... what is weird `12321324143432142352546534636534343243525425` is matching."*

Technically, the pattern should include *word-boundaries*, or some *static value* to anchor to.

> *"... How to make my regex pattern validate 14 digits string as a first part and if something presented after, it should looks like `-{numbers/letters}_{numbers}_{numbers}` ..."*

Here is an example, with the *group names* omitted.  I've included the full pattern, at the end of this text.

```
\b(\d{4})(\d{3})([A-Z\d]{3})(\d{4})(?:-([A-Z\d]+)(?:_(\d+)(?:_(\d+))?)?)?(?: |$)
```

And, here is an example application.

```java
String r = "\\b(?<part1>(?<year>\\d{4})(?<day>\\d{3})(?<number>[A-Z\\d]{3})(?<sequence>\\d{4}))(?:-(?<lastPart>(?<letter>[A-Z\\d]+)(?:_(?<num1>\\d+)(?:_(?<num2>\\d+))?)?))?(?: |$)";
String s = "12233255555555 valid\n"
         + "12233255555555- invalid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A valid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A_ invalid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A_1 valid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A_1_ invalid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A_1_1 valid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A__1 invalid\n"
         + "12233255555555-A__ invalid";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int i = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("match " + ++i);
    for (String k : m.namedGroups().keySet())
        System.out.printf("  %s = '%s'%n", k, m.group(k));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
match 1
  year = '1223'
  lastPart = 'null'
  number = '555'
  letter = 'null'
  day = '325'
  num1 = 'null'
  part1 = '12233255555555'
  sequence = '5555'
  num2 = 'null'

match 2
  year = '1223'
  lastPart = 'A'
  number = '555'
  letter = 'A'
  day = '325'
  num1 = 'null'
  part1 = '12233255555555'
  sequence = '5555'
  num2 = 'null'

match 3
  year = '1223'
  lastPart = 'A_1'
  number = '555'
  letter = 'A'
  day = '325'
  num1 = '1'
  part1 = '12233255555555'
  sequence = '5555'
  num2 = 'null'

match 4
  year = '1223'
  lastPart = 'A_1_1'
  number = '555'
  letter = 'A'
  day = '325'
  num1 = '1'
  part1 = '12233255555555'
  sequence = '5555'
  num2 = '1'
```

Here is the complete pattern.

```
\b(?<part1>(?<year>\d{4})(?<day>\d{3})(?<number>[A-Z\d]{3})(?<sequence>\d{4}))(?:-(?<lastPart>(?<letter>[A-Z\d]+)(?:_(?<num1>\d+)(?:_(?<num2>\d+))?)?))?(?: |$)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your examples have an underscore `_` after the first part, but your regex has a hyphen `-`, so I've corrected that error by assuming your examples are correct.

The main problems with your regex are:

1. you made all the subparts of the optional part optional - they shouldn't be optional. The *whole* optional part should be there or not.
2. the separator (the underscore/hyphen) must be part of the optional group. The way you've coded it makes it *required* after the first part, whether or not the final optional group is present.

Try this:

```
^(\d{4})(\d{3})([A-Z0-9]{3})(\d{4})(_([A-Z0-9]+)_(\d+)_(\d+))?$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/wZvrAVfPdcycK2).

I've removed all the group names for readability.

I also added `^` and `$` because I don't know how you're using it. If you're using `String#matches()`, you can remove those.

Comment: Hello, ended up with something like following ```^(\d{4})(\d{3})([A-Z0-9]{3})(\d{4})(-?([A-Z0-9]+)(_?(\d+))?(_?(\d+))?)?$``` and it works fine, except one case: more then 14 digits string (1232132414323134242342423) is still valid. https://regex101.com/r/BJItcS/1